# Why did grunt's logging capabilities become deprecated?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, github, gruntjs

It seems `grunt`'s default logging functions, accessed through `grunt.log.<method>`, have become deprecated. `grunt`'s repo page on GitHub has a new repository, first commit less than 2 weeks ago, called "grunt-legacy-log", where "legacy" implies "old, not used anymore except for backwards compatibility". Also, the main page detailing the API for these functions, http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.log, has a broken link at the top of the page, whose target gives a 404 error.

Why has this happened? All I could find through a simple Google search was a [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/1130) where the commenters seem to have planned this out, but whatever they did wasn't documented anywhere else that I could find. They seem to be referring to an earlier discussion, but they don't link to it. `grunt`'s blog says `grunt`s "logging API has been broken out into a separate module, `grunt-legacy-log`, in order to facilitate maintenance", but it doesn't expand on what this means. Why are they performing maintenance? Why is it being called "legacy", if they are not deprecating it?

So is the logging capability deprecated? If so, what are we supposed to do to log in `grunt` now? I assume we won't have to use JavaScript's `document.write` method, even if it worked for `grunt`, but what are we expected to use? If not, what is going on and why is `grunt` using the word "legacy"?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the broken link on `grunt.log`. Updated https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-docs/commit/22a08f6e0f28db68c1bcd0976f132ee0a23f3143 and will be reflected online soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Background: I am on the Grunt team.*

`grunt.log` is not deprecated. The current implementation has been moved into `grunt-legacy-log` as `grunt.log`'s internals will eventually be replaced by [prolog](https://github.com/cowboy/node-prolog).

Please continue to use the `grunt.log` methods. I highly doubt we'll ever deprecate that API. At most, we might break backwards compatibility with how some of the APIs work. But that would only happen during a minor or major bump in Grunt, i.e. `v0.4.x` to `v0.5.0` and it will be well documented on how to migrate.

You'll likely see more APIs being moved out into their own libraries. This is part of Grunt's effort to make these internal libraries more accessible to the larger Node.js community and easier for us to maintain. If any are deprecated, they'll be marked as such and we'll give users a migration path.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's great when someone who works for the company can answer questions like this on a site like StackOverflow.  I like what you're doing with `grunt`, keep it up! So does this mean `grunt` will have a dependency on `grunt-legacy-*`, or will these packages be part of `grunt` AND separate packages? How will you be handling this?

Comment: Grunt isn't owned by a company. The Grunt team is some of many volunteers who contribute their free time to the project. You can become a contributor to Grunt and help steer the project as well :) Yes Grunt will use the legacy packages as dependencies: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/package.json#L66 which are available on npm (and will continue to be available in the future).

Comment: Sorry, I meant all you guys that are *volunteering* in `grunt` are doing a great job. I guess I meant "It's great when someone who works for the company **of people who work on `grunt`** can answer questions like this on a site like StackOverflow". If I get better at making web apps I may become a `grunt` volunteer :).